# Where can I find the Microsoft Java API documentation

Tags: java, jvm

Can someone provide me with the link to the MS Java API documentation?

(Sadly, I still have use of the original MS java API which I had a link to until recently when I lost my web browser bookmarks.)

Comment: Are you talking about the old MS JVM? http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/Interoperability/Java/Default.aspx

Comment: "when I lost my web browser bookmarks": one reason I use Xmarks extension for Firefox: http://www.xmarks.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find the documentation of Microsoft's SDK for Java (SDKDocs40.exe)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808720/where-can-i-find-the-documentation-of-microsofts-sdk-for-java-sdkdocs40-exe)

Comment: > "Xmarks extension for Firefox: xmarks.com" - Is there an equivalent for Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa253229(v=VS.60).aspx

Did some more digging and found it myself.  Thanks for the quick comments folks.